# Not your usual 'Class' may not respond to 'method' warning - iPhone / Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, warnings

I know that you must have already seen this warning and given the solution too often, but my case is a little bit special.
I get the warning only for one class, but everything (imports, implementation, header-file, and so on) is set correctly. I'm coding Objective-C in XCode for some time now, and would say for myself, that I've earned quite the experience with iPhone programming. I'm totally sure, that everything is alright.
It seems, that XCode somehow did not recognize the changes I made to the class. It's even suggesting some methods that aren't in this class anymore. I checked the project out on another mac and build it there, and everything was fine, no warnings at all.
I do not want to reinstall XCode to get rid of these annoying warnings that shouldn't be there. Any suggestions on how to tell XCode that it has to buy itself some glasses?
Help is very much appreciated =)

EDIT: Okay, just so that nobody can say, I'm crazy or anything, here is the code and a small explanation at the end:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface URLConnection : NSObject {
NSString *theURL;
NSMutableData *receivedData;
id delegate; // delegate needed for handling response
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *receivedData;
@property (retain) id delegate;

- (NSData*) sendSynchronousRequest:(NSData*)_postData;
- (void) sendRequest:(NSData*)_postData;

- (void)setDelegate:(id)val;
- (id)delegate;

@end

#import "URLConnection.h"


@implementation URLConnection

@synthesize receivedData, delegate;


- (id) init
{
if (self = [super init]) {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (![[defaults stringForKey:@"bankurl"] isEqualToString:@"<Custom URL>"]) {
        theURL = [[defaults stringForKey:@"bankurl"] retain];
    } else {
        theURL = [[defaults stringForKey:@"bankurl_list"] retain];
    }
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}
return self;
 }

 - (void)setDelegate:(id)val
 {
    delegate = val;
 }

 - (id)delegate
 {
return delegate;
 }


 /* send a synchronous request (specified for xml documents) */
 - (NSData*) sendSynchronousRequest:(NSData*)_postData
 {
NSString *_urlString = theURL;
NSMutableURLRequest *_urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[_urlRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_urlString]];
[_urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[_urlRequest setValue:@"text/xml" 
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[_urlRequest setHTTPBody:_postData];

// response
NSHTTPURLResponse *_urlResponse = nil;
NSError *_error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSData *_responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:_urlRequest 
                                              returningResponse:&_urlResponse 
                                                          error:&_error];
[_urlRequest release];
NSString *_result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_responseData 
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response code: %d", [_urlResponse statusCode]);
if ([_urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [_urlResponse statusCode] < 300) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", _result);
}
return _responseData;
}


/* send an asynchronous request (specified for xml documents) */
- (void) sendRequest:(NSData*)_postData
{
NSMutableURLRequest *_urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[_urlRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theURL]];
[_urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[_urlRequest setValue:@"text/xml" 
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[_urlRequest setHTTPBody:_postData];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:_urlRequest delegate:self];
[_urlRequest release];
 }


 /* 
  * NSURLRequest Delegate
  * if a response comes back, clear receivedData to make room for the response data
  */
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 {
[receivedData setLength:0];
 }


/* 
 * NSURLRequest Delegate
 * if data is received, append the chunk of data to receivedData
 */
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[receivedData appendData:data];
}


/* 
 * NSURLRequest Delegate
 * when all response data has been stored, call didFinishDownload() in the class
 * which set itself as the delegate
 */
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{
[delegate didFinishDownload:receivedData];

[connection release];
//[receivedData release];
}



- (void) dealloc
{
[theURL release];
theURL = nil;
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

First of all, yes, I know that the line "[delegate didFinishDownload:receivedData];" will throw warnings, but that's not the issue I'm writing about. When I press alt+esc to see method suggestions, all the above are in the list, but also "sendRequest:theURL:" and "sendMail:" which have been removed long ago.

Comment: I don't know why, but the warnings have been removed after starting XCode today. Beats me... Problem solved, I think...

Answer (score 0):

Have you done Clean All Targets? (It's in Xcode's Build menu.)

Comment: @zhar:  including the precompiled headers?

Comment: If you mean, emptying the cache, yes, even this.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode (the application menu) --> Empty Caches...

Answer (score 0):

--Delete your build from the folder wher you save the app,
--delete from simulator or device.
--clean all targets.
--click xcode then empty Caches...

Now No warning you will see .

Comment: I did everything in this order, many times before, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure you don't have another copy of this header somewhere in your machine that xcode might be finding before it finds your most up-to-date copy?

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure. I even renamed the project. I think it has something to do with the SVN repository, but can't find the source =/